# How to read a text present in the content description

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I want to verify how many Wifi signal bars present in my android mobile.To verify this, i want to read a content description of a Wifi signal bar and print it.

The below mentioned code fails to work(fails to read the text in the content description).

```
UiSelector wifi = newUiSelector().className("android.widget.ImageView").index(1).descriptionContains("wifi");
        System.out.println("Bars =" +wifi);
```

note: I'm not using adb

Comment: Can you please explain your use case/requirement, because there are some other ways to get the wifi signal strength, if you actually need only that.

Comment: I'm not using adb...in my mobile status bar, Wifi signal strength is displayed.The current status is displayed in the content description(three bars), class:android.widget.FrameLayout..I want to print the text present in content description

Answer (score 0):

hope it works

```
int Levels=5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), Levels);
    System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
```

Comment: I'm not using adb...in my mobile status bar, Wifi signal strength is displayed.The current status is displayed in the content description(three bars), class:android.widget.FrameLayout..Basically I want to print the text in Cmd prompt output present in content description

Comment: i tried the above mentioned code, "wifiManager" cannot be resolved error throws in the second line

Comment: if i use WifiManager in second line(WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()), "Cannot make a static reference to non static method getConnectionInfo()from the type WifiManager" message displays

Comment: WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
then call wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

Comment: When i try to run the below mentioned code, it does nothing..public void sstrength(Context context) {
        int Levels = 5;
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); 
        int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(),Levels);
        System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
               
 }

Comment: is it possible to use context in `uiautomator` ?